# Stop f:ajax From Auto Including JavaScript jsf.js?ln=javax.faces

Tags: jsf-2

I am using the standard f:ajax component in a couple of my pages, and I would like to have this component not automatically import the jsf.js?ln=javax.faces JavaScript file so that I can load it myself in a copy that I just save along with my other static resources in my app.

Is there a way to disable the automatic include of this JavaScript file, and am I going to be missing out anything if I serve it myself?

Thanks.